# Quicksands Simile?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

I am looking for that very specific sutta in the Pâli Canons wherein it is made plain that such a one not having himself attained to liberation, is not qualified to liberate other. The simile, I think, is about being mired in quicksands...

Thank you for your kind attention, your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The sutta you are looking for can be found in the [*MN 8 - Sallekha Sutta: Effacement*](https://suttacentral.net/en/mn8#table-of-contents).

Here the Buddha gives the following teaching to Ven. Cunda:

> (The way of extinguishing)
>
> 16. “Cunda, that one who is himself sinking in the mud should pull out another who is sinking in the mud is impossible; that one who is not himself sinking in the mud should pull out another who is sinking in the mud is possible. That one who is himself untamed, undisciplined, [with defilements] unextinguished, should tame another, discipline him, and help extinguish [his defilements] is impossible; that one who is himself tamed, disciplined, [with defilements] extinguished, should tame another, discipline him, and help extinguish [his defilements] is possible

Answer (score 0):

**Quicksand similes / references**

Following are the only [2 Quicksand](https://suttacentral.net/search?query=Quicksand) references as per SC.

> Attaining true liberation /
>   ​is just like this:
>   once rid of afflictions, /
>   ​the quicksand of desires,
>   no one knows /
>   ​whither he went.
>
> - [Dabba enters Nirvāṇa](https://suttacentral.net/en/sa-2.15)

And

> “Like as a strong man lends a helping hand
>   To weaker, sunk in mire or in quicksand:
>   So, Queen Pancati, thou hast saved me here,
>   With verses sung so sweetly in mine ear.”

[Hatthi-Pala Jātaka](https://suttacentral.net/en/ja509)